# How can i pass SSL Certificates using CURL ( Laravel )

Tags: php, laravel, api, https, php-curl

> **cURL error 35: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)**

i got this error when im trying to send data to external website which it has HTTPS.Below is my code:

```php
     public static function createMessage($recipients,$notification,$_data)
    {
        $data = [
            'recipients' => $recipients,
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $_data,
        ];
       
        return self::sendRequest('post','messages',$data);
    }

    public static function sendFormId($form_id,$page_id)
    {
        $data = array(
          'page_id' => $page_id, 'form_id' => $form_id
        );
        
        return self::sendRequest('post',$url,$data);
    }

    public static function sendRequest($method,$endpoint,$data)
    {
        $hook = new FbHook($method,$endpoint,$data);
        
        return $hook->send();
    }
```

### fbHook.php

```php
public function send()
    {

        $client =  new Client(['verify' => false]);
        $options = [
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.env('FBHOOK_APP_TOKEN'),
                'environment'=>env('APP_ENV'),
            ),
        ];

        if(count($this->from_data)){
            $options['form_params'] = $this->from_data;
        }
        
        $method = array_get($this->supportMethodList(),strtolower($this->method),'post');
        $full_url = $this->getFullUrl();
        $response = $client->{$method}($full_url,$options);
        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        $content = json_decode($content,true);
        $status = array_get($content,'status',false);

        \Log::debug('URL '.$full_url.' Status '.$status. 'post .'.json_encode($options));

        return $status;
```

Comment: What does the `Log` returns? Is `$full_url` returns a `https` or `http`url?

Comment: @iamab.in the log when http there no issue but the website that i want is in https return error 'cURL error 35: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html'

Comment: Try updating cURL